# ¿Cómo puedo obtener que la foto de mapa de bits es vertical u horizontal?

Tags: java, android, bitmap

No encontré lo que realmente necesito en google y stackoverflow, quiero entender que una foto que acabo de capturar de la cámara es vertical u horizontal, Código:

```
path_img= ("image_url");   
Bitmap  photo = null ;
photo = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path_img );
int imageHeight = photo.getHeight();
int imageWidth = photo.getWidth();
```

Cuando capturo la foto en la imagen de mi teléfono Altura y anchura es siempre igual quiero decir que si tomo una foto vertical u horizontal siempre es 4126x3096, quiero que el tamaño de la foto horizontal sea (ancho: 1024 altura: 720) y vertical sea (ancho: 720 altura : 1024)

Por lo que he estado viendo hay modelos de android que te dan una resolucion siempre la misma dandoles igual si es vertical o horizontal como por ejemplo mi samsung J5 pero con otro movil con un Huawey P-smart me da las dimensiones bien segun es vertical o horizontal.

Como podria detectar eso por codigo para que en cualquier modelo me funcionase?

Gracias.

Comment: tendrías que leer el [EXIF data](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format) en el tag orientation te dice como fue tomada ref: https://sirv.com/help/resources/rotate-photos-to-be-upright/#EXIF_orientation_values

Comment: Si Malbarez también leo el Exif pero no entiendo porque hay modelos de moviles que me dice la orientación y hay modelos de moviles que no me dicen la orientación. En este caso el Samsung J5 me dice la orientación de 90, 180, 270... pero en otros modelos de moviles siempre me dice a 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final haciendo pruebas la solución que encontré es esta.

```
private static Bitmap TypeResize(String filePath, Bitmap bm, SettingsStoreModel settingsSave) {
    ExifInterface exif = null;
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    try {
        exif = new ExifInterface(filePath);
        int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

        switch (orientation) {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED:
                //Movil no lo detecta porque el width i el height es el correcto por ejemplo 1000x3000 o 3000x1000
                    if(bm.getWidth() > bm.getHeight()) {
                        switch (settingsSave.getCameraResolution()) {
                            case SettingCameraResolution.SmallVGA:
                                bm = calculateInSampleSize(bm, 800, 600);
                                matrix.preRotate(0);
                                bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), matrix, true);
                                break;
                            default:
                                bm = calculateInSampleSize(bm, 1024, 768);
                                matrix.preRotate(0);
                                bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), matrix, true);
                                break;
                        }
                    }else {
                        switch (settingsSave.getCameraResolution()) {
                            case SettingCameraResolution.SmallVGA:
                                bm = calculateInSampleSize(bm, 600, 800);
                                matrix.preRotate(0);
                                bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), matrix, true);
                                break;
                            default:
                                bm = calculateInSampleSize(bm, 768, 1024);
                                matrix.preRotate(0);
                                bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), matrix, true);
                                break;
                        }
                    }

                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
  //El width y el height sea vertical o horizontal es el mismo por tanto tenemos que mirar la rotacion de la imagen con ExifInterface.
                switch (settingsSave.getCameraResolution()) {
                    case SettingCameraResolution.SmallVGA:
                        bm = calculateInSampleSize(bm, 800, 600);
                        matrix.preRotate(90);
                        bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), matrix, true);
                        break;
                    default:
                        bm = calculateInSampleSize(bm, 1024, 768);
                        matrix.preRotate(90);
                        bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), matrix, true);
                        break;
                }
                break;
        //El width y el height sea vertical o horizontal es el mismo por tanto tenemos que mirar la rotacion de la imagen con ExifInterface.
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
                switch (settingsSave.getCameraResolution()) {
                    case SettingCameraResolution.SmallVGA:
                        bm = calculateInSampleSize(bm, 800, 600);
                        matrix.preRotate(0);
                        bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), matrix, true);
                        break;
                    default:
                        bm = calculateInSampleSize(bm, 1024, 768);
                        matrix.preRotate(0);
                        bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), matrix, true);
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                //Movil no detecta el width i el height sa de detectar la rotacio i resiza despres pujar-ho segons la rotacion ( lo que pasa amb el meu movil ).
                switch (settingsSave.getCameraResolution()) {
                    case SettingCameraResolution.SmallVGA:
                        bm = calculateInSampleSize(bm, 800, 600);
                        matrix.preRotate(270);
                        bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), matrix, true);
                        break;
                    default:
                        bm = calculateInSampleSize(bm, 1024, 768);
                        matrix.preRotate(270);
                        bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), matrix, true);
                        break;
                }
                break;
        }
        return bm;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Con esta función que hice me funciona para todos los moviles tanto para los que capturan la imagen de una manera como los que la capturan para otra.

Answer (score 0):

No me quedó claro si es tu app la que capturará la foto o solo la procesa luego de tomada.

Si la toma tu app, quizá puedas obtener información de otro sensor para identificar la orientacion del telefono al momento de la captura.

Si no es asi, pues ya no se me ocurre nada. Lo que define la orientacion cuando vemos una imagen es la interpretacion que le damos como humanos al contenido de la misma, y a puro codigo no creo que se pueda hacer eso...